# Child classes implement a MooseX::Interface with MooseX::ABC (Abstract Base Class)

Tags: perl, interface, moose, abstract-base-class

I am trying to force all child classes of an Abstract Base Class to implement an interface. When I try add `with '<interface>'` to the ABC, it requires me to implement the required methods immediately and add `sub <method> {}` for each interface method.

To Illustrate the Problem,

```
package drawAPI {
   use MooseX::Interface;
   require 'draw';
   one;
}

package shape {
   use MooseX::ABC;
   with 'drawAPI';
}

package square {
   extends 'shape';
    #here is where having a draw subroutine would be inforced
   sub draw {};
}
```

Does anyone know a way to do this? or can recommend a different set of modules to accomplish this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for [MooseX::ABC](https://metacpan.org/pod/MooseX::ABC) states "NOTE: This module is almost certainly a bad idea. You really want to just be using a role instead!". The documentation for [MooseX::Interface](https://metacpan.org/pod/MooseX::Interface) states that "Interfaces are just roles with a few additional restrictions..." Your choice of modules suggests that you want Moose to look and work like Java, which is a lost cause. The good news is that [Moose Roles](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Moose/lib/Moose/Manual/Roles.pod) can almost certainly provide much if not all of the *behavior* you're looking for. Furthermore, you might be surprised by some of the powerful things that you can accomplish with Roles that don't have an analog in Java.